# PHP build array from variables

Tags: php, arrays

So I have a variable which I explode:

```
$values = explode ('|', $split);
```

This can contain any number of values from 1 to 10+

I have another big array let's call it `$tree`. I need to loop round the `$values` whilst building up an array based on the `$tree` variable.

E.g:

```
$newArray = $tree [$values [0]][$values [1]];
```

But this needs to be done dynamically based on the number of elements in the `$values` array.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: And a `foreach` is not enough?

Comment: lol. many lookalike answers here. choose in all this. but I wonder, what is it exactly you want to do? any example of your arrays? give us a print_r or something like that :)

Comment: wait, you really mean that your keys in the $tree correspond to the values wxploded by split? do they always go by pairs, or sometimes you want the values associated to the first and third $value?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($values as $key => $val)
{
    $newArray[] = $tree[$val][$values[$key + 1]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a foreach loop that goes to every single value you have and then put them in the $tree array something like:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($values as $index => $value)
{
    $newArray[] = $tree[$value][$value[$index + 1]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

create a temporary array from $tree and iterate through the values getting each index:

```
$result = $tree;
foreach ($values as $val){
    $result = $result[$val];
}
```

This way you go down one level deeper into $tree with each value supplied in $values, and $result holds the value stored in $tree at the point you have reached. For example if you have a navigation tree, $values would be the "breadcrumb" of the current navigation position, and $result is the remaining tree from this point downwards.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want. It goes through pairs of elements of `$values`, using them as the indexes into `$tree` to add to `$newArray`

```
$newArray = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count(values); $i += 2) {
    $newArray[] = $tree[$values[$i]][$values[$i+1]];
}
```

Comment: yeah, seems you got it right. or closest :) deletd mine since I was just going to duplicate yours.

Answer (score 0):

```
$values=array(0, 1, 3);
$tree=array("First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth");
$newarray=array();

for ($i=0; $i<count($values); $i++)
{
    $newarray[]=$tree[$values[$i]];
}

echo(implode($newarray,", "));
```

Something like that what you were looking for?